# Display just the subcategories of the chosen category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

This is the code I currently have:

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Choose a category"} %>
<%= f.collection_select :subcategory_id, Subcategory.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Choose a subcategory"} %>
```

All it does is to display in one dropdown **all** the categories and in another **all** the subcategories.
like this [image: the drop downs.]

> **Question:** How to make just the specific subcategories appear depending on the chosen main category. With the code above, it shows all the categories and all subcategories.

Everything is linked in the model, the has_many, and belongs_to...and category_id and subcategory_id..everything is working properly, I just don't know how to show the specific subcategories within chosen category.

My attempt:

```
  <% if (Category.where(:name=>"Intro")) do |d| %>
    <% d.subcategories.each do |subcategory| %>
      <%= link_to subcategory.name, gigs_path(subcategory: subcategory.name) %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

This code gives an error. I though to say if, for example, the user picks the category called "Intro" than list all the "Intro subcategories". But it didn't work out - my code is obviously wrong.

*Thank you.*

Answer (score 8):

I assume you want this to happen without reloading the page? You won't get around a bit of JavaScript then. Here's the general workflow:

- when the category dropdown is changed, send an Ajax request which will respond with JavaScript and insert the correct values into the Subcategory dropdown.

For the sake of this example I will just assume that your form (the model that belongs to a category) is a post. You didn't seem to mention the model.

Let's try this:

**views/posts/_form**:
I will wrap the subcategories selct box in a `subcategories_select` div, which enables us to replace the whole content later.

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, { prompt: "Choose a category" }, id: "category_id" %>

<div id="subcategories_select">
 <%= f.collection_select :subcategory_id, Subcategory.all, :id, :name, { prompt: "Choose a subcategory" }, { disabled: true } %>
</div>
```

**assets/javascripts/posts.js.erb**

```
# select the element to watch for changes
$('form').on('change', '#category_id'), function() {
  var category_id = $(this).val(); # save the category_id set in the first dropdown

  $.ajax({
    url: "/categories/" + category_id + "/get_subcategories", # a custom route, see routes.rb further down
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "script", # we expect a response in js format
    data: { "category_id": category_id } # the only value we will need to get the subcategories
  });
});
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
# we need a custom route for our get_subcategories action
resources :categories do
  member do
    get :get_subcategories, defaults: { format: "js" }
  end
end
```

**controllers/posts_controller.rb**
Important: I assume that a category has_many subcategories and subcategories have a category_id, which meansbelong_to a category. If that's not the following won't make sense.

```
# our custom controller action
def get_subcategories
  @subcategories = Subcategory.where(category_id: params[:category_id])
end
```

**app/views/posts/get_subcategories.js.erb**
Here we will replace the content of our subcategories_select div and insert a collection_select with the appropriate options.

```
$('#subcategories_select').html("<%= j collection_select(:post, :category_id, @subcategories, :id, :title), { prompt: 'Select subcategory...' }, { disabled: false } %>");
```

Please note that I did this from the top of my head, so there might be errors, but this is one approach to dynamically populate select boxes, or in general change anything on a page without reloading.

Comment: Are you sure it must be **assets/javascripts/posts.js.erb** i mean with the ending .js.erb ?i did all you said,and the category is clickable and shows all the categories as it should,and the subcategories no matter what i do,are not clickable.Please give me your bitbucket username,i will send an invitation,to my repo.Thank you.

Comment: You can put the JavaScript part anywhere you want as long as it is included with the asset pipeline. For the sake of this example, just put it in application.js temporarily and see if it works. As I said, I wanted to outline one approach to solve this problem. While I used this approach in many of my apps, I didn't test this particular example. You will probably need to pay attention to the server logs and the JS console in your browser to catch any errors. And yes, the ending is fine - js.erb enables you to use ruby in your javascript response, similar to html.erb

Comment: @MikeMcCallen - Please accept this answer, it provides copy-paste level of support.

Answer (score 1):

This is what solved my question

in javascript folder (masonry gem must be installed)

```
$ ->
  $('#gigs').imagesLoaded ->
    $('#gigs').masonry
      itemSelector: '.box'
      isFitWidth: true

  $(document).on 'change', '#gig_category_id', (evt) ->
    $.ajax 'update_sub_categories',
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: {
        category_id: $("#gig_category_id option:selected").val()
      }
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        console.log("AJAX Error: #{textStatus}")
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        console.log("Dynamic country select OK!")
```

in Gig controller

```
respond_to :html, :js, :json
  def update_sub_categories
    @cats = Subcategory.where(category_id: params[:category_id]).all
    respond_with(@cats)
  end
```

Than i created a partial in gig view
_subcategory.html.erb
and put this code

```
<option value="<%= cat.id %>"><%= cat.name %></option>
```

than another partial in gig view called _update.html.erb
put this code

```
$("#gig_subcategory_id").empty().append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "subcategory", :collection => @cats, :as => :cat)) %>")
```

Finally in the view to display the category and subcategory,i used

```
  <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Choose a category"} %>
  <%= f.collection_select :subcategory_id, Subcategory.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Choose a subcategory"} %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Filtering a collection_select with js may be very difficult. I recommend using group_collection_select which filters the data if the relations are correct. Asumming you have a data model that looks something like the one mentioned in the above answer, the view should have something like this:

## views/posts/_form:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name,    
               { prompt: 'Select a category' }, { id: 'category-select' }) %>

<%= f.grouped_collection_select :subcategory_id, Category.all, :subcategories, 
          :name, :id, :name, { include_blank: 'Select a sub category' },
                                               { id: 'subcategory-select' } %>
```

Right now you will be able to see both select forms but the grouped_collection_select box shows kind of nested options. in order to show only the necesary subcategories we will need to do some changes in the javascript, in my case y use coffee and my files will be named .coffee instead of .js.erb

## app/assets/javascripts/posts.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
  subcat = $('#subcategory-select').html()
  $('#category-select').change ->
    cat = jQuery('#category-select').children('option').filter(':selected').text()
    options = $(subcat).filter("optgroup[label='#{cat}']").html()
    if options
      $('#subcategory-select').html(options)
    else
      $('#subcategory-select').empty()
```

I owe my answer to this [source](http://sajinmp.in/posts/dynamic-select-in-rails) where you can find more details about using group_collection_select

Comment: Awesome, much easier, than fiddling around AJAX, works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

So the embedded ruby that you wrote gets evaluated before being sent to the 'client side'. What that means is that the code you wrote gets turned into static HTML and sent to the user.

What you want is to use something that can provide logical operations on the user's browser.  That means javascript.

Checkout: AngularJS: https://angularjs.org/

Comment: @MikeMcCallen front-end actively communicates with the back-end through the ajax calls. So that function from 'front-end' calls functions on the 'back-end', then it receives the results and handle them. I recommend you to read more about ajax, and think about how the web works ;)

Comment: I must have misunderstood your question.  It would appear to me that you're trying to change the content of the second drop-down menu ('Choose a Subcategory') when a user chooses an option in the first ('Choose a Category').  It looks like your trying to accomplish this on the server side which, in some circles, is considered erroneous.

What you might try is executing an AJAX call to your controller every time a user changes an option in the first menu, and then using that response to populate the options in the second menu.  But again, this is slightly unorthodox.

Comment: This can absolutely be achieved in rails.  Using a simple json api.  Unless I misunderstood your response.

Comment: @MikeMcCallen Your last response might mislead other readers into thinking its possible to use your embedded ruby to dictate client-side behaviors that should be handled through javascript.  Please accept this answer or delete the post so it can be closed.

Comment: i still didn't received an answer.I tried a new method to use `Category.find(1).subcategories` and now it shows all the subcategories of the category with "id: 1",but i can't do the same thing for categories,for some reason.

Comment: Thats because the embedded ruby is evaluating the `Category.find(1).subcategories` and sending the result as static html to the user when he makes an initial request for the view.  What you want is to have those values change upon user input.  Once the user has the view, it cannot re-interact with the logic you're hoping for.  You need to have a controller action that will respond to an HTTP request, containing a category, and yield that specific category's subcategories (probably in json format).  With that json, you can update the available 'subcategories'