# JQuery can't find the Sub Category ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I followed the instructions in [this question's answer by emmanuel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831340/display-just-the-subcategories-of-the-chosen-category) and the form now finds the Category ID and submits it but does not find the Sub Category ID associated with the Category and does not save it.

The params are taken which can be noted by this, 
 `Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PTRTGGblf3HoWNXmanKl8TIP7F4j/QKTLN2Wd6oKSQWSXV27qioztUpXgb6YjHEroaWf8dgTzUIgQiRBK2XxWQ==", "post"=>{"title"=>"200k", "description"=>"FMxd123", "category_id"=>"2", "subcategory_id"=>"9"}, "commit"=>"Create Post"}`

It then shows the error message on my screen (with my error partial) that "Sub Category must exist. The SQL output is like so:

```
  (0.2ms)  begin transaction
 Category Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]

   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendering posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered shared/_errors.html.erb (0.8ms)
  Category Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"

  SubCategory Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "sub_categories".* FROM "sub_categories" WHERE "sub_categories"."category_id" = ?  [["category_id", 1]]
  SubCategory Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "sub_categories".* FROM "sub_categories" WHERE "sub_categories"."category_id" = ?  [["category_id", 2]]
  SubCategory Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "sub_categories".* FROM "sub_categories" WHERE "sub_categories"."category_id" = ?  [["category_id", 3]]
```

My Posts.coffee:

```js
jQuery ->
  subcat = $('#subcategory-select').html()
  $('#category-select').change ->
    cat = jQuery('#category-select').children('option').filter(':selected').text()
    options = $(subcat).filter("optgroup[label='#{cat}']").html()
    if options
      $('#subcategory-select').html(options)
    else
      $('#subcategory-select').empty()
```

And the part where category_id and sub_category_id are taken in the form with select boxes:

```html
  <p>
 <%= f.label :category_id%>
 <%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name,    
                { prompt: 'Select a category' }, { id: 'category-select' }) %>
  </p>
  <p>
 <%= f.label :subcategory_id%>
 <%= f.grouped_collection_select :subcategory_id, Category.all, :sub_categories, 
          :name, :id, :name, { include_blank: 'Select a sub category' },
                                               { id: 'subcategory-select' } %>
   </p>
```

Confused as to how it isn't working because it made my category_id get saved when it wasn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post an url for code so that it can be tested directly?

Comment: want a github link?

Comment: yes if that is possible

Comment: @GraveyardQueen https://github.com/jayhaz/jquerryissue , make sure you rake db:seed and rake db:migrate

Comment: can you send the url of your coded website hosted on github ,it will be hosted on github.io

Comment: @GraveyardQueen http://jayhaz.github.io/jquerryissue/.

Comment: Is that what you want???

Comment: yes that is what i wanted,but it is not working right?

Comment: do you have any working url for your code?because i am not sure about how to do the db setup and all that

Comment: I can deploy to heroku if that is what you want? My jquery code doesn't work

Comment: Are you able to get the sub category id from the query?

Comment: no just category id? i don't really understand js which is why i am confused. I can go into the console and querry the SubCategories associated with the Category but I think there is something wrong with my js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gone through your code and I found some errors.

Here are the changes you should make to make your project work.

**As you mentioned, it is not any jquery issue.**

**Error1**:-

You have taken the `subcategory` model name as `SubCategory` and table is `sub_categories`, so the foreign key should be `sub_category_id`, but you have taken `subcategory_id`.

**So either you have to change the column in the database, or tell rails to take the name.**

Here are the changes to tell rails about it.

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  # belongs_to :sub_category
  belongs_to :sub_category, class_name: 'SubCategory', foreign_key: 'subcategory_id'
end
```

**sub_category.rb**

```
class SubCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  # has_many :posts, :primary_key => "subcategory_id"
  has_many :posts, class_name: 'Post', primary_key: 'id', foreign_key: 'subcategory_id'
end
```

Check the lines commented.

**Now the post show view also has some errors which I solved.**

**Error2**:-

**posts/show.html.erb:**

```
<% content_for :title, @post.title %>
<% navigation_add @post.title, post_path(@post) %>
<h2 align="center">Title: <%= @post.title %></h2>
<div class="well col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
    <h4 class="center description"><strong>Description:</strong></h4>
    <hr>
    <%= simple_format(@post.description) %>
    <hr>
    <p>Post ID: <%=@post.id%></p>
    <hr>
    <div class="post-actions">
        <%= link_to "Edit this post", edit_post_path(@post), class: "btn btn-xs btn-primary" %>
        <%= link_to "Delete this post", post_path(@post), method: :delete,
        data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete the post?"},
        class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger" %>
        <%= link_to "View all posts", posts_path, class: "btn btn-xs btn-success" %>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Last but not the least, your `seeds.rb` is wrong.**

**Error3**:-

```
category_1 = Category.where(name:"cat1").first_or_create(name:"cat1")
category_2 = Category.where(name:"cat2").first_or_create(name:"cat2")
#SUB
# 1
SubCategory.where(name: 'g', category_id: category_1.id).first_or_create
SubCategory.where(name: 'er', category_id: category_1.id).first_or_create
#L2
SubCategory.where(name: 'tu', category_id: category_2.id).first_or_create
SubCategory.where(name: 'dual', category_id: category_2.id).first_or_create
```

Add this script to `posts/new.html` to get your dropdown work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  var subcat;
  subcat = $('#subcategory-select').html();
  return $('#category-select').change(function() {
    var cat, options;
    cat = jQuery('#category-select').children('option').filter(':selected').text();
    options = $(subcat).filter("optgroup[label='" + cat + "']").html();
    if (options) {
      return $('#subcategory-select').html(options);
    } else {
      return $('#subcategory-select').empty();
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

**Here is the working image:**

[image]

Comment: That works however now the jquery doesn't filter out the subcategories not associated with the main category in my new post

Comment: Thank you very much, is it not better to but that script somewhere else and not in the html.erb?

Comment: yes you can move that script to a js file and call it with this view. pls vote my answer if you find it uesful :)

Comment: Moved it to my form partial so I can use it when editing as well, thank you.